# How to parse true as boolean in json schema?

Tags: .net, json.net, njsonschema

How can I parse the following schema using NJsonSchema? Is it valid to use `"default": true`?

```
    var problemJsonSchema = """
{
    "title": "JSONSchema",
    "default": {},
    "oneOf": [{
            "$ref": "#/definitions/JSONSchemaObject"
        },
        {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/JSONSchemaBoolean"
        }
    ],
    "definitions": {
        "JSONSchemaBoolean": {
            "title": "JSONSchemaBoolean",
            "description": "Always valid if true. Never valid if false. Is constant.",
            "type": "boolean"
        },
        "JSONSchemaObject": {
            "title": "JSONSchemaObject",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "$id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "default": true
            }
        }
    }
}
    """;

    var metaSchema = JsonSchema.FromJsonAsync(problemJsonSchema).Result;
```

This code throws with error,

> One or more errors occurred. (Unexpected initial token 'Boolean' when populating object. Expected JSON object or array. Path 'definitions.JSONSchemaObject.properties.default', line 21, position 27.)

Comment: Your JSON is malformed.  Upload it to https://jsonlint.com and you will get three errors, two about trailing commas (which can be ignored by must serializers) and one about a missing closing `}`.  The missing closing `}` happens because you indented `"JSONSchemaObject":` one less level than appropriate.  Is there any chance you made an error about that?

Comment: @dbc Thank you for pointing that out. I've fixed it now. Unfortunately the error remains.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the type of the property (like you did with id) and a default value as true.

```
var problemJsonSchema =
"""
{
    "title": "JSONSchema",
    "default": {},
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/JSONSchemaObject"
        },
        {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/JSONSchemaBoolean"
        }
    ],
    "definitions": {
        "JSONSchemaBoolean": {
            "title": "JSONSchemaBoolean",
            "description": "Always valid if true. Never valid if false. Is constant.",
            "type": "Boolean"
        },
        "JSONSchemaObject": {
            "title": "JSONSchemaObject",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "$id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                 "default": {
                     "type": "boolean",
                     "default": true
                 }          
            }
        }
    }
}
""";
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not the author of this schema. Is it not a vaild schema then?

Comment: Yes  this is invalid schema

Comment: Also if you have the model you can convert it to the json scheme easily, if that is the case